# Are Q library version 0.9.7 promises compatible with ES2015 promises?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, q

Are `Q` library version `0.9.7` promises compatible with ES2015 promises?

Can I add a function that returns an ES2015 Promise into an existing `Q` promise chain and expect it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Q does follow the [Promises/A+ standard](https://promisesaplus.com/) (saying "coined it" would be a bit too much, but to the point), and is therefore interoperable with all ES6 promises.

Also, in the other direction, the [`Q.Promise`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qpromiseresolver) constructor does follow the ES6 standard [since v1.0.1.](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/CHANGES.md#101); for even better compatibility use [v2.x](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/tree/v2).

Answer (score 0):

You can see more detail about compatibility of Q with ES2015 in this article:

http://www.2ality.com/2014/10/es6-promises-api.html

You can migrate from one to another as they are similar in the way you use them.